# Run script with 1 min delay

Tags: script

How to make delay for mining scrypt. I want, when start or restart windows, this script start automatically after 1min. Thank you very much and regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running windows 7 or newer. Use native delay function:

```
timeout /t 60
```

In earlier versions there was no native delay support and following workarounds were available:

- Use one of POSIX ports (cygwin for example) and utilized *sleep*
- Compile a simple C / C++ program that contains delay
- Use ping or netstat to generate a delay (non-deterministic behavior)